# Global Navigation Menu hidden to the back side of web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I'm having a global navigation menu and sub menu under that.

The problem is this drop down sub menu is hidden when a dashboard web part comes in page. That is the bottom part of the sub menu goes to back side of the web part. I just need it to be visible and always on top of any item in the page.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can solve this "error" with a correct styling in your CSS-file. Hit F12 and highlight the element blocking your drop-down and set `height`, `width`, `float` and `overflow` attributes to correct values.

But my first test would be to add `display: block;` to the element blocking the drop-down and see what effect you get from that action.

A final tip: customizing CSS is hard in SharePoint and you might have to use 
`!important` as an extra attribute to every style change you try to accomplish. But that applies only when you already have a solution full of important statements. In all other cases, important should be avoided.

Comment: Never use !important!! It will get you in the end. You need to just get good at selectors.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson That's true. I forgot myself and was refering to our custom code where !important is user too often in the older solutions. I'll revise the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson I strongly agree with Marc here

Comment: There are a few places where Microsoft uses !important (horrible) so you can only beat that with !important. That should really be the only excuse.

Answer (score -1):

for SP 2013, just do `ul.dynamic{z-index: 100 !important;}`

It works amazingly.